# Why a new call of a method with exclamation mark affects all previous calls of that method?

Tags: ruby, syntax

I'm sorry if this is a duplicate - I couldn't find anything similar in the existing posts.

I understand the difference between methods like `shuffle` and `shuffle!`. However, I am confused why calling the method more than once would result in changing the variables of all objects that previously referred to it? I'd expect once we apply a method, that the variable gets a value and we're done with it. Not that it continues to refer to the method call and the argument passed and that it would get re-evaluated later on.

I thought it's best to demonstrate with an example:

```
irb(main):001:1* def shuffle(arr)
irb(main):002:1*   arr.shuffle!
irb(main):003:0> end
=> :shuffle
irb(main):004:0> arr = [1,2,3,4]
=> [1, 2, 3, 4]
irb(main):005:0> one = shuffle(arr)
=> [4, 2, 3, 1]
irb(main):006:0> two = shuffle(arr)
=> [1, 2, 4, 3]
irb(main):007:0> one
=> [1, 2, 4, 3]
```

So, here I'd expect `one` to stay `[4, 2, 3, 1]`. However, with each new call, all previous ones would get equated to the latest result of the method call. I realise it should have something to do with calling it with the same argument `arr`, but still doesn't quite make sense.

Comment: Because `one` only holds a reference to the array, not a duplicate of the original array. That means if you change the array then all variables holding a reference to the array will return the changed array. You can test that they all return the same array by calling `object_id` on these variables. If you want to avoid this behavior you have to `clone` or `dup` the array before assigning it to a variable.

Comment: "I understand the difference between methods like shuffle and shuffle!" - what would you say is that difference?

Comment: `arr`, `one`, and `two` all refer to the same object. That's because `arr.shuffle!` (with a `!`) shuffles `arr` and then returns (the shuffled) `arr`. You probably expect your method to return a _new_ array instead. Which is what `arr.shuffle` (without `!`) would do.

Comment: "what would you say is that difference?" - I read it as "this will modify the receiver", however, didn't expect it to also modify anything that was previously "equated" to the receiver since I didn't think these previous variable hold references to the objects when a method is applied, but expected that instead they get assigned the value. Which I now understand is wrong.
Thanks to all who replied, it's clearer now.

Comment: @noname _"expected that instead they get assigned the value"_ – in Ruby, all values are objects: `1` is an object, `"foo"` is an object and `[1, 2, 3]` is an object (holding other objects). There isn't anything else. If you pass an object into a method and that method returns the object, you'll get the very same object back. (although `shuffle!` modifies the object, it's still the same object, identity-wise)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Array#shuffle!`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.3/Array.html#shuffle-21-method) shuffles the array in-place and returns its receiver:

```
ary = [1, 2, 3, 4]
ary.equal?(ary.shuffle!) #=> true
```

Assigning the result from `shuffle!` to another variable doesn't change this. It merely results in two variables referring to the same array:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
b = a.shuffle!

a #=> [2, 4, 1, 3]
b #=> [2, 4, 1, 3]

a.equal?(b) #=> true
```

You probably want a *new* array. That's what [`Array#shuffle`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.3/Array.html#shuffle-method) (without `!`) is for:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
b = a.shuffle

a #=> [1, 2, 3, 4]
b #=> [2, 4, 1, 3]
```

Even if `shuffle` returns the element in the original order, you'll get another array instance:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
b = a.shuffle until b == a

a #=> [1, 2, 3, 4]
b #=> [1, 2, 3, 4]

a.equal?(b) #=> false
```